# How to enable GC logging for Hadoop YARN ResourceManager and ApplicationTimeline, while preventing log file overwrites and capping disk space usage

Tags: hadoop, logging, garbage-collection, hadoop-yarn, diskspace

We recently decided to enable GC logging for Hadoop YARN ResourceManager and ApplicationTimeline servers on a number of clusters (exact version varies) as a aid to looking into YARN-related memory and garbage collection problems.  While doing this, we want to avoid two problems we know might happen:

- overwriting of the log file when a YARN RM or AT server restarts for any reason
- the logs using too much disk space, leading to disks getting filled

When Java GC logging starts for a process it seems to replace the content of any file that has the same name. This means that unless you are careful, you will lose the GC logging, perhaps when you are more likely to need it.

If you keep the cluster running long enough, log files will fill up disk unless managed.  Even if GC logging is not currently voluminous we want to manage the risk of an unusual situation arising that causes the logging rate to spike up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set some JVM parameters when starting the YARN servers, meaning you need to make some changes to yarn-env.sh.  You could set the parameters in YARN_OPTS, but that would have a broader impact than just the ResourceManager and ApplicationTimeline servers, so instead you will probably want to set then in both `YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS` and `YARN_TIMELINESERVER_OPTS`.

Now lets discuss the JVM parameters to include in those.

To enable GC logging to a file, you will need to add `-verbose:gc -Xloggc:<log-file-location>`.

You need to give the log file name special consideration to prevent overwrites whenever the server is restarted.  It seems like you need to have a unique name for every invocation so appending a timestamp seems like the best option.  You can include something like `date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'` to add a timestamp.  In this example, it is in the form of YYYYMMDDHHMM.  In some versions of Java you can put "%t" in your log file location and it will be replaced by the server start up timestamp formatted as YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.

Now onto managing use of disk space. I'll be happy if there is a simpler way than what I have.

First, take advantage of Java's built-in GC log file rotation. `-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M` is an example of enabling this rotation, having up to 10 GC log files from the JVM, each of which is no more than approx 10MB in size. 10 x 10MB is 100MB max usage.

With the GC log file rotation in place with up to 10 files, '.0', '.1', ... '.9' will be added to the file name you gave in `Xloggc`. .0 will be first and after it reaches .9 it will replace .0 and continue on in a round robin manner.  In some versions of Java '.current' will be additionally put on the end of the name of the log file currently being written to.

Due to the unique file naming we apparently have to have to avoid overwrites, you can have 100MB *per RM or AT server process invocation*, so this is not a total solution to managing disk space used by the YARN GC logs. You will end up with a set of up to 10 GC log files on each server invocation -- this can add up over time. The best solution (under *nix) to that would seem to be to use the logrotate utility (or some other utility) to periodically clean up the GC logs that have not been modified in the last N days.

Be sure to do the math and make sure you will have enough disk space.  Note that you might be running a ResourceManager and a ApplicationTimeline on the same master server.

People frequently want more details and context in their GC logs than the default, so consider adding in `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`.
Putting this together, you might add something this to yarn-env:

```sh
# this function takes the name of a YARN component as input and returns the JVM options
# to enable GC logging for the component.  The option string is set in the variable named
# as the second arg
function yarn_gc_log_opts_for_component()
{
    # get function args
    local component_name=$1
    local  __resultvar=$2

    # calculate GC log name
    local timestamp_str=`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'`
    local gc_log_name="{{yarn_log_dir_prefix}}/$USER/yarn-${component_name}-gc.log-${timestamp_str}"

    # calculate GC logging options for enablement, rotation, and format
    local gc_log_enable_opts="-verbose:gc -Xloggc:$gc_log_name"
    local gc_log_rotation_opts="-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M"
    local gc_log_format_opts="-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"

    # combing these options and return the result
    local gc_log_opts="$gc_log_enable_opts $gc_log_rotation_opts $gc_log_format_opts"
    eval $__resultvar="'$gc_log_opts'"
}
```

# get options for GC logging for YARN ResourceManager servers and put them into use
    yarn_gc_log_opts_for_component "resourcemanager" YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_GC_LOG_OPTS

```sh
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS $YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_GC_LOG_OPTS"
```

# get options for GC logging for YARN AT servers and put them into use
    yarn_gc_log_opts_for_component "timelineserver" YARN_TIMELINESERVER_GC_LOG_OPTS

```sh
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS $YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_GC_LOG_OPTS"
```

In the above, you can change `{{yarn_log_dir_prefix}}/$USER` to wherever you want the GC logs to go (you probably want it to go the the same place as YARN RM and AT server logs).  You can change the log file naming too.

If you are managing your Hadoop cluster with Apache Ambari, then these changes would be in YARN service > Configs > Advanced > Advanced yarn-env > yarn-env template.  With Ambari, `{{yarn_log_dir_prefix}}` will be automatically replaced with the YARN Log Dir Prefix defined a few rows above the field.

GC logging will start happening upon server restart.